# Pathfinder Post-processing incorrectly- Data severely shifted

Tags: trimble, pathfinder, post-processing

I'm new to Pathfinder (just transferred our license over to my computer). I post-processed my data and exported to ESRI shapefile. My data from the east end of Long Island, New York displays off the coast of Africa. I've tried post processing a few different files, ones that post-processed fine on my coworkers computer, and all have the same issue. I can't seem to find any settings or help documents that address the issue. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "set a projection to create the .prj file but I did solve my problem. After reading your comment I looked around for the .prj file [image: I realized I didn't have anything set for my projection file (see below)]

I followed the steps I found here:
https://mapsupport.seilerinst.com/2012/06/07/where-to-find-the-projection-files-for-coordinate-systems-to-use-for-trimble-gps-pathfinder-office-export/

All seems to work now. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds projection related. What projection was the data taken in and what is the coordinate system in ArcMap? My experience with Pathfinder is that you have to "set projection" to create the .prj file for ArcGIS.